# Swift example for GCDAsyncSocketDelegate

Tags: ios, swift, gcdasyncsocket, gcdasyncudpsocket

Refer to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42547555/i-am-looking-for-some-examples-on-gcdasyncudpsocket-but-found-none-that-works) I have some issues while receiving data from GCDAsyncSocket and can't find a working Swift example.

```
import UIKit
import CocoaAsyncSocket


class DiscoveryViewControllerTest: UIViewController, GCDAsyncSocketDelegate{
    let host = "192.168.55.1"
    let port:UInt16 = 4000

    let cmdDeviceInformation = "?0600\r";
    let cmdDeviceIStandByeExit = "?060B\r";
    let cmdDeviceIStandByeEnter = "?060A\r";
    var mSocket: GCDAsyncSocket!

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        print("Started wifi scanning!\n")

        mSocket = GCDAsyncSocket(delegate: self, delegateQueue: DispatchQueue.main)
        do {
            try mSocket.connect(toHost: host, onPort: port)
        } catch let error {
            print(error)
        }
        print("Connecting to instrument...!\n")
    }

    public func socket(_ socket: GCDAsyncSocket, didConnectToHost host: String, port p:UInt16){
        print("didConnectToHost!\n");

        let data = cmdDeviceIStandByeEnter.data(using: .utf8)
        print("TX: ", terminator: " ")
        print(data! as NSData)
        mSocket.write(data!, withTimeout:10, tag: 0)

        mSocket.readData(withTimeout: -1, tag: 0) //This line was missing!

    }

    public func socket(_ sock: GCDAsyncSocket, didWriteDataWithTag tag: Int) {
        print("didWriteData");
    }

    public func socket(_ sock: GCDAsyncSocket, didReceive trust: SecTrust, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> Void) {
        print("didReceiveData")

        let rxData:Data = Data()
        mSocket.readData(to: rxData, withTimeout: 5, buffer: nil, bufferOffset: 0, tag: 0)
        print("RX: ", terminator: " ")
        print(rxData as NSData)
    }

    public func socket(_ sock: GCDAsyncSocket, didRead: Data, withTag tag:CLong){
        print("didRead!");
    }

    public func socketDidDisconnect(_ sock: GCDAsyncSocket, withError err: Error?) {
        print("didDisconnect!")
    }
}
```

The connecting and writing method is running but the "didReceive" Method is never called.

**Console output:**

> Started wifi scanning!
>
> Connecting to instrument...!
>
> didConnectToHost!
>
> TX:  <3f303630 410d> didWriteData

**EDIT**
I solved my problem and changed the question code to a ready to use example.

Comment: Is "socketDidDisconnect" called with some error?

Comment: @RJVKumar No it isn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found my fault. The clue is to enable reading just behind the `mSocket.write()` function call in `socket didConnectToHost()`. The complete function looks like this:

```
public func socket(_ socket: GCDAsyncSocket, didConnectToHost host: String, port p:UInt16){
    print("didConnectToHost!\n");

    let data = cmdDeviceInformation.data(using: .utf8)
    print("TX: ", terminator: " ")
    print(data! as NSData)
    mSocket.write(data!, withTimeout:10, tag: 0)

    mSocket.readData(withTimeout: -1, tag: 0) // Add this line
}
```

BTW: I edited my question to create a ready to use example for everyone.